# Are these lcd and motor-shields stackable?

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, motor, lcd, arduino-motor-shield

first of all, I'm kindly apologizing for asking such stupid questions, but as my electronic-knowledge is dramatically limited, you are my only hope to get my problem solved.

I'm pretty new to Arduino and my plans are to stack a lcd shield on a motor shield, which is stacked on the Arduino.

My setup would be the following:

- Arduino MEGA2560
- LCD-Shield http://www.sainsmart.com/arduino/arduino-shields/lcd-shields/sainsmart-1602-lcd-keypad-shield-for-arduino-duemilanove-uno-mega2560-mega1280.html
- Motor-Shield http://www.sainsmart.com/arduino/arduino-shields/motor-shields/sainsmart-l293d-motor-drive-shield-for-arduino-duemilanove-mega-uno-r3-avr-atmel.html

My target is to enter specific values trough the LCD-shield (with its buttons) and to control a stepper-motor related to those.

Now to my question: Can I realize my project with the mentioned parts and are the two shields stackable (with head extentions on the motor-shield) without creating interferences?

Thank you very much for your time and answers in advance.

Best regards,

irie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't look like it.

The LCD board uses digital pins 4-10 and analog 0

The motor board uses digital pins 3-12 if all motors are used.

If you need to stack boards look for boards that use I2C since they can share a single data bus.